# MySQL syntax error with insert and set user variable

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help explain to me why this query would be giving me the error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @frodoBaggins = LAST_INSERT_ID();INSERT INTO actor (Lastname, Firstname, Ge' at line 1` ?

```
INSERT INTO actor (Lastname, Firstname, Gender) VALUES ('Wood', 'Elijah', 'M');
SET @frodoBaggins = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO actor (Lastname, Firstname, Gender) VALUES ('Astin', 'Sean', 'M');
SET @samwiseGamgee = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO movie (movietitle, year) VALUES ('The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', '2001');
SET @FOTR = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO movie (movietitle, year) VALUES ('The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers', '2002');
SET @TTT = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO movie_role (a_id, m_id, character_name, character_type) VALUES (@frodoBaggins, @FOTR, 'Frodo Baggins', 'Hero');
INSERT INTO movie_role (a_id, m_id, character_name, character_type) VALUES (@frodoBaggins, @TTT, 'Frodo Baggins', 'Hero');
INSERT INTO movie_role (a_id, m_id, character_name, character_type) VALUES (@samwiseGamgee, @FOTR, 'Samwise Gamgee', 'Hero');
INSERT INTO movie_role (a_id, m_id, character_name, character_type) VALUES (@samwiseGamgee, @TTT, 'Samwise Gamgee', 'Hero');
```

Comment: In the error message, the assignment is done with `:=` and in your posted code you have just the equals sign. Have you corrected that?

Comment: Oops. Yes, I have.Either way the error is the same.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked like a charm. Maybe in your actual code, are you missing a semicolon at the end of the first line or something like that?

Comment: If it works like a charm then why does this website say it has a syntax error: https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Comment: Tried the syntax checker myself. It looks, it can only process one query at a time. Tried it also with multiple mysql queries of my own and got an error on first line. If I run the check for each query by itself, it doesn't fail.

Comment: How are you running the queries in a script or one by one command line?

Comment: Using Java with JDBC. All in one query.

Comment: Fixed it by using `addBatch`.